# Windows Save As dialogs: how to view all file types by default when saving?

Tags: windows, macos, windows-explorer

Having come from OSX I'm used to seeing all file types visible in the Save As dialog window when saving any file.

In Windows it's typically restricted to only showing the file types of the file being saved, eg: JPEG.

This can be frustrating and take longer to find similarly named files and see folder contents more easily.

Is there a way to force Windows to show all file types across all apps in Save As dialogs, while still keeping the current file type to be saved (eg: JPEG)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the programmer(s) of the application have to build it in before the code is compiled.

If this is something you wanted to do then you would need to be able to use a program which can access RAM addresses on the fly and change the code on the fly.

If it was programmed in VB then here is a code snippet of what the programmer would have to consciously do:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()


    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" // <-- THIS ONE


    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True 

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then 
            ' Code to write the stream goes here.
            myStream.Close()
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Was hoping there might be some registry tweak or utility, as so many apps I've tried lack this ability, but from what you've said it seems like a hard-coded limitation.